# Unable to change Appcompat theme from light to holo dark

Tags: java, android, android-theme, android-appcompat, android-actionbaractivity

I am trying to change the theme of my app completely, This is what I modified & tried :

`styles.xml` in values folder is

```
<resources>

<!--
    Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
    by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.
-->
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo">
    <!--
        Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
        res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
        backward-compatibility can go here.
    -->
</style>

<!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
</style>

</resources>
```

values-v11 `styles.xml`

```
<resources>

<!--
    Base application theme for API 11+. This theme completely replaces
    AppBaseTheme from res/values/styles.xml on API 11+ devices.
-->
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo">
    <!-- API 11 theme customizations can go here. -->
</style>

</resources>
```

values-v14 `styles.xml`

```
<resources>

<!--
    Base application theme for API 14+. This theme completely replaces
    AppBaseTheme from BOTH res/values/styles.xml and
    res/values-v11/styles.xml on API 14+ devices.
-->
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo">
    <!-- API 14 theme customizations can go here. -->
</style>

</resources>
```

Mainifest.xml

```
<application
   .....
   android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
   .......
</application>
```

I am using `ActionBarActivity` & `appcompat_v7` but the app crashes by `java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com...}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity`

Am I missing something...?

How can I solve this problem?

Please help...

Thanks in advance !

---

**EDIT:** When using Appcompat theme , the theme was light, the code was:

So, using appcompat theme my `styles.xml` in values folder was

```
<resources>

<!--
    Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
    by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.
-->
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <!--
        Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
        res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
        backward-compatibility can go here.
    -->
</style>

<!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
</style>

</resources>
```

values-v11 `styles.xml`

```
<resources>

<!--
    Base application theme for API 11+. This theme completely replaces
    AppBaseTheme from res/values/styles.xml on API 11+ devices.
-->
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <!-- API 11 theme customizations can go here. -->
</style>

</resources>
```

values-v14 `styles.xml`

```
<resources>

<!--
    Base application theme for API 14+. This theme completely replaces
    AppBaseTheme from BOTH res/values/styles.xml and
    res/values-v11/styles.xml on API 14+ devices.
-->
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- API 14 theme customizations can go here. -->
</style>

</resources>
```

Mainifest.xml

```
<application
   .....
   android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
   .......
</application>
```

And I dont know how to change appcompat theme from light to holo dark. Please help

Comment: did you read the error? it is telling you that you need to use a theme that is in `AppCompat` the theme `android:Theme.Holo` is not an AppCompat theme

Comment: please look my edited question

Answer (score 35, accepted):

As tyczj pointed, you need to use `Theme.AppCompat` as a parent for your themes if your app uses `appcompat_v7`. `Theme.AppCompat` is visually the same as `Theme.Holo` (dark).

See the [article about styling the ActionBar](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html#AndroidThemes) on the Android documentation for more information.

Comment: You used `Theme.AppCompat.Light` and `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar`. Have you tried just `Theme.AppCompat`? I use it in the app I'm developing which uses `appcompat_v7` as well and it's definitely dark.