# Extending AppCompatActivity not letting me use Holo or Material themes

Tags: android, themes

I'm trying to create an app with `android:Theme.Holo.Light` and extending the Activity by AppCompatActivity. Android is throwing errors saying that I must use AppCompat theme.

My question is:

If I don't extend AppCompatActivity, I don't get material look in API level below 21 and if I extend Activity and set Holo theme, I don't get any errors but at the cost of missing the Material feel in the older devices. How do I overcome this limitation?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25162657/unable-to-change-appcompat-theme-from-light-to-holo-dark

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Theme.AppCompat if you are extending AppCompactActivity
You can use **Theme.AppCompat**. It is similar to **Theme.Holo**

Comment: But it wll not look same as Holo. Divider line is missing.