# Toolbar textcolor won't change

Tags: android, android-layout, android-toolbar

I'm trying to change the textcolor in toolbar to white but the color wont change.

Things i've tried:

1- Changing the `app:theme=app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"`

2- trying to do it programmatically: `toolbar.setTitleTextColor(0xFFFFFFFF);`

3- The last one which code appears under:

Custom style: ToolBarstyle:

Res/style

```
  <style name="ToolBarStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@android:color/white</item>
        <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@android:color/white</item>
        <item name="actionMenuTextColor">@android:color/white</item>
        <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerArrowStyle</item>
    </style>
```

Res/Layout

```
   <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:theme="@style/ToolBarStyle"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat"
        app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />
```

Java file:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    /* Toolbar */
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Nostrils");
    toolbar.setTitleTextColor(0xFFFFFFFF);
    // Back icon
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    initNavigationDrawer();
}
```

Photo from the emulator:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/d3NNb.png

Comment: Of course, `Theme.AppCompat` is Dark! Check my answer. No need to do that on Java side tho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the answer but since its part if a collapsing toolbar i added this code (and it worked):

```
app:collapsedTitleTextAppearance="@style/CollapsedAppBar"
        app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@style/ExpandedAppBar"
```

to :

```
<android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
```

with:

```
   <style name="ExpandedAppBar" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
        <item name="android:textSize">24sp</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
    </style>

    <style name="CollapsedAppBar" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
        <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
    </style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your toolbar to

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
       xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
       android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
       android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
       app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
       android:id="@+id/toolbar">

        <TextView
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_gravity="start"
           android:textSize="16dp"
           android:textStyle="bold"
           android:maxLines="1"
           android:ellipsize="end"
           android:textColor="@color/white"
           android:layout_marginRight="?attr/actionBarSize"
           android:gravity="center"
           android:id="@+id/welcome_textView"/>

     </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Access this textView

```
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) view.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    TextView textToolHeader = (TextView) toolbar.findViewById(R.id.welcome_textView);

    textToolHeader.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.your_color));
```

Answer (score 0):

For the toolbar set:

```
app:titleTextColor="@android:color/white"
```

or in your app theme set:

```
<item name="android:textColorPrimary">@android:color/white</item>
```

Answer (score 0):

**https://stackoverflow.com/a/25162981/4409113**

> `Theme.AppCompat` is visually the same as Theme.Holo (dark)

So, just change parent:

```
<style name="ToolBarStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
```

To:

```
<style name="ToolBarStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
```

Because you already have a `Toolbar` in your layout and this theme will make the color white.